# How do I solve : Error: object 'a' not found

Tags: rstudio

I 'm running into an error and don't know how to fix it.

If I just want to make a vector: kat <- (a, b, c) it trows an error: object 'a' not found.
The workspace is empty, I cleaned it
when I run ls() I get 
character(0)
if I make another vector, it always gives me an error always with first element of vector not found.

How is it possible?
Can someone tell me what to do?
Thanks!

Comment: sorry I wrote an error

Comment: kat <- c(a, b, c)

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: The thing is that if you don't assign previously a value to a, b and c you'll have this error.
If your wish is to create a vector with 3 characters: a, b and c. You have to pass them as characters!
kat <- c("a", "b", "c")
Otherwise, the code will think that they're variables (that are unassigned).

Comment: I forgot to put the letters in quotes, Thanks

Comment: @ Dave: "thanks !"